# Allow jQuery access to a PHP file but deny everything else

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have a PHP file that processes a form, call it "form-process.php"

In a JS file I catch the submit of the form and use jQuery .post() to send the info to this PHP file.

```
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this),
        action = form.attr('action');

    $.post(
        action,
        form.serialize(),
        function(data) {
            // display results on page
        }
    )
})
```

**First part of the question:**

What's the best way for me to secure the file form-process.php so it can't be directly accessed at www.website.com/form-process.php but the jQuery can still access it for processing.

**Second part of the question:**

In the form-process.php I am using htmlspecialchars() to strip potential HTML entered into the form. Is there any other *major* security issues one would suggest addressing?

Comment: What you want can be done but it can also be bypassed, by modifying the header of the request.

Comment: "First part of the question" - there is no way to secure and there is no need to secure it.
"Second part of the question" - it depends on how you are going to use that data.

Comment: @Cheery ok so instead of denying access I should just check for POST variables and if none are set then display some arbitrary message? The data will be used to generate an email using PHPMailer

Comment: What do you mean `accessed only by jquery`? Do you mean PHP should only accept AJAX requests? an AJAX request is only different by checking the `$_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"]`, which can also be spoofed.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer for the first question**

There is no way to make `form-process.php` accessible only from jQuery. You could add a hash to the POST data that is required to execute `form-process.php`, but potential attacker can read that hash just by viewing your JavaScript code. You can obfuscate your code, but still, the attacker can just check what data is sent over AJAX and still can get the hash. jQuery is executed on the client side, and no matter how you would try to secure your code, it will be always possible to replicate all your security mechanisms by an attacker.

**Answer for the second question**

Filtering the data properly is the best way to secure the `form-process.php`. Analyse what kind of data you can only accept and create filters that will only accept this kind of data and nothing else. Take a look at this function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php

http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

When you expect a field to contain URL, accept only URLs (`FILTER_VALIDATE_URL`). When you expect email address, accept only email addresses (`FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`), etc.

When a user must be logged in to submit the form, you can also verify if the user is logged in in the `form-process.php` file as well.